# Search a column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

The following takes in the `user_time` as input. And returns the actual time if it existed in the `df['time']` or returns the closest time whether it is +1 or -1 ahead or behind of the seconds specified. The range in not more than +120 seconds. So if it is not in the 120 seconds, then it does not exist.

```
#Following Format always 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss' 
user_time = '2018-04-10 13:00:03'


if user_time not in df['time']:

        closest_time = 
        #df.loc[df['time'].str.contains(closest_time )]
```

I am not sure how to find the closest time to pass it to the function and print out that row if the actual time does not exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should work fine:

```
In [38]: sd = pd.DataFrame({'date':pd.date_range('2018-01-01 00:00:00','2018-01-5 00:00:00',freq='min')})

In [39]: sd['date'] = pd.to_datetime(sd['date'])

In [41]: sd.iloc[(sd['date'] - pd.to_datetime('2018-01-03 01:12:23')).abs().argsort()][:1]
Out[41]: 
                    date
2952 2018-01-03 01:12:00
```

or

```
In [50]: sd.iloc[(sd['date'] - pd.to_datetime('2018-01-03 01:12:23')).abs().argmin()]
Out[50]: 
date   2018-01-03 01:12:00
Name: 2952, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: This is nice, but note that it's not necessary to sort to find the minimum.

Comment: @AmiTavory yeah i just replaced it with argmin().

Comment: @shivsn this works great ! Can I please ask you to add comments/explain In [41]. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Say you start with

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    't': pd.to_datetime(['2018-04-10 13:00:03', '2018-04-10 14:00:03'])})
```

Then

```
(df.t - pd.to_datetime('2018-04-10 23:00:03')).dt.total_seconds().abs().argmin()
```

finds the index of the row whose absolute-value seconds difference to some time (`'2018-04-10 23:00:03'`) is smallest.

- `(df.t - pd.to_datetime('2018-04-10 23:00:03'))` finds the difference to the time.
- `dt.total_seconds()` converts the difference in total seconds.
- `abs()` takes the absolute value.
- `argmin()` returns the index of the minimum.

Thanks @MaxU for the improvement!

Comment: Do we need `apply` here? `(df.t - pd.to_datetime('2018-04-10 23:00:03')).dt.total_seconds().abs().idxmin()`

Comment: @AmiTavory i dont think you need .dt.total_seconds() also

Comment: @shivsn Yeah, thanks - I upvoted your answer for that.